# Mock a global variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a function in main module which takes in two values and performs opertaions on them.This uses a global variable which is created before calling this function

```
def calc(keys,values):
    if globalvar == "calc":
        return sum(keys)
    else:
        return sum(values)
```

Now in unittesting

```
class Testcalc(TestCase):
@mock.patch('module.globalvar ', "calc")
def test_unit(self,calc):
    keys=[1,2,3]
    values=[4,5,6]
    sum=module.calc(keys,values)
    """
    check asserts
    """
```

I am getting an type error with invalid arguments.

```
TypeError('test_unit() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)',)
```

Could anyone show me the correct way of mocking the global variable

Update:
This worked for me not sure why

```
class Testcalc(TestCase):
@mock.patch('module.globalvar')
def test_unit(self,var):
    keys=[1,2,3]
    values=[4,5,6]
    var="calc"
    sum=module.calc(keys,values)
    """
    check asserts
    """
```

Thank you everyone

Comment: Show the full error.

Comment: TypeError('test_unit() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)',)

Comment: Please include the line that calls `test_unit()`, i.e. where you use it.

Comment: I don’t think your error is related to the way you’re mocking the global. But without a [mcve] it’s hard to be sure. What you’ve posted here has an IndentationError, and a slightly variation on the same indentation problem could cause an error much like the one you’re seeing, but I doubt that’s your problem. So show us code that actually reproduces your problem instead of a different one.

Answer (score 8):

> A `module.globalvar = 'anything'` should be enough, no need to `mock.patch`

```
def test_calc2(self):
    keys = [1, 2, 3]
    values = [4, 5, 6]

    module.globalvar = "calc"
    sum = module.calc(keys, values)
    self.assertEqual(module.globalvar, 'calc')
    self.assertEqual(sum, 6)

    module.globalvar = 'other'
    sum = module.calc(keys, values)
    self.assertEqual(sum, 15)
```

> This works using PropertyMock

```
@mock.patch('module.globalvar', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock)
def test_calc3(self, mocked_globalvar):
```

> This is syntax right, but will fail the test, since the globalvar has to be set by PropertyMock

```
@mock.patch('module.globalvar')
def test_unit(self, mock_globalvar):
```

Comment: Thank u for replying @Gang,
So can I use module.globalvar = 'anything' in the test_unit  function as a paramter and it would work instead of patch?

`def test_unit(self,var):
    keys=[1,2,3]
    values=[4,5,6]
    module.globalvar = 'calc'
    sum=module.calc(keys,values)
    """
    check
`

Comment: @Ram, sorry the `module.globalvar` is right, I included in the update, the `@mock.patch` part is wrong, it only works with `mock.PropertyMock` for globalvars, class attributes etc